# git log for specific commit in branch

Tags: git

I was searching a certain commit id in a specific branch, although the commit isn't in that specific branch I've got a result, while in git log there are no results.

> git log commit_id # finds commit
>
> git check a # branch 'a' doesn't contain commit_id
>
> git log # search for commit_id with no results.

is that a bug or by design? if not a bug, then why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

`git log` is the list of commits in that specific branch, it's not a bug. If you just run `git log` without the `<sha1>` it'll show the commits in reverse order for that particular branch.

If you want to view a commit, you can use `git show <sha1>` to view that particular commit, which isn't branch specific.

Comment: IMHO, if using git log with specific commit it should keep the log's 'filter', and not show the commit. basic UX?

Comment: when using git log, it implicitly does it to current branch, so why when adding a commit_id, it implicitly uses all references? maybe I'm way off but that's misleading.

Comment: Not really. When you leave off everything it uses the current branch as the default, but `git log <sha1>` shows the log history for that specific commit in the repository. It's because you're assuming that it's only going to operate on the current branch that it doesn't make sense straight away.

Answer (score 5):

You need to remember that branches are just references to commits. Meaning if you say `git log <branch>`, you are actually saying `git log <commit to which this branch points>`. And with that, git goes to that commit(or branch which is just a pointer) and shows history from there.

If you call `git log <commit_id>`, it makes no difference. git still goes to that commit and starts log from there.

I'll repeat again for your understanding, branch is just a pointer. They exist just to make our lives easier and are not at all necessary. Git is only interested in commits they point to.

Go ahead and explore what's contained in `refs/heads` folder in `.git` directory.